# How to avoid the evaluation of fractions?

Tags: python, sympy

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26669706/evaluating-jacobian-at-specific-points-using-sympy/26671670#26671670) nicely explains how one can calculate a jacobian using `sympy`.

My question is whether there is a way to avoid the evaluation of fractions which can lead to "ugly" numbers. For example,

```
from sympy import exp, Matrix, symbols

x0, x1, mu, E, T = symbols('x0 x1 mu, E, T')

X = Matrix([exp(x0 / 8.314 / T), -x1 + mu*x0*(1 - x1**2)])
Y = Matrix([x0, x1])
print(X.jacobian(Y))
```

This yields

```
Matrix([
[0.120279047389945*exp(0.120279047389945*x0/T)/T,               0],
[                                mu*(-x1**2 + 1), -2*mu*x0*x1 - 1]])
```

What I would like to have is that `0.120279047389945` is kept as `1 / 8.314`. Is that possible?

Comment: How is `8.314` less ugly than `0.12027`? The problem is that `8.314` is a float, so it's already an approximation.

Comment: @EricDuminil: I edited the question, then it should now become obvious that it is uglier ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`8.314` is a float, so it's an approximation. Sympy thinks there's no harm in changing `1/8.314` to `0.12027`.

You could replace `8.314` with a Symbol:

```
>>> from sympy import Symbol
>>> magic_factor = Symbol('8.314', positive=True, real=True)
>>> X = Matrix([exp(x0 / magic_factor / T), -x1 + mu*x0*(1 - x1**2)])
>>> print(X.jacobian(Y))
Matrix([[exp(x0/(8.314*T))/(8.314*T), 0], [mu*(-x1**2 + 1), -2*mu*x0*x1 - 1]])
```

Comment: ...or just define another symbol that you'll know is `8.314`, that way sympy is not even tempted. This results in `Matrix([[exp(x0/(T*c))/(T*c), 0], [mu*(-x1**2 + 1), -2*mu*x0*x1 - 1]])`

Comment: This then gives `500*exp(500*x0/(4157*T))/(4157*T)` which is not much better.

Comment: @Amadan: Yes, I guess I will go for this solution; feel free to add it as an answer.

Comment: @Cleb: Changed.